# Rails best practice for calling a model method from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, controller

I have `Model_a`, `model_a_controller` and `Model_b`. I have a method in `model_b` that I would like to call in `model_a_controller`. But I am not sure what the best practice for doing so would be. This is my method right now:

```
def method
   id = Model_b.method
   .... some other stuff
end
```

Im calling the method directly from the model but is it better rails practice to perhaps make an instance of the model and then call the method from that instance? Something like

```
    def method
   @model_b = Model_b
   id = @model_b.method
   .... some other stuff
end
```

Im not quite sure what the best practice would be or if my alternative would make sense; Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: I would argue that any good answer will highly depend on what the method does? If it is an instance or class method? If it is highly related to the domain of model b or if it could also fit into the domain of model a too or both or into an independent helper class?

Comment: @spickermann The method gets a value from the `Model_b` database table

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you'd like to achieve and what's the context. I can only answer with some quick guiding questions that might be a start point for your own decision making.

I see two different threads in you question:

1. **Class method vs instance method**
   For this it doesn't matter where you call the `method_b`. It's about its logic and responsibility. What does this method suppose to do? Do you need a `Model B` instance (e.g. `@instance_B.valid?`)? Or is it a behaviour related to class only or all Model B instances (e.g. `Model_B.count`)? Think about the outcome of this method and what you need to achieve it.
2. **Where to call the `method_b`**
   As a rule of thumb, a good practice in rails is to keep skinny controller.
   Is there any relationship between `model A` and `model B`? Then probably it's better to call the `method_b` in the `model A`. Maybe you should consider adding the service layer for that?
   https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial
   Consider relationships between models and the controller actions.

There are no strict rules that always work. It depends on the business context, the app design and direction of the development.
If you provide more specific example, then we can give more specific advice and discuss pros & cons of different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a service object like this:
In app, create a folder services(`app/services`)

Inside services folder you can organize all the services for your project.

```
services/model_b_service/model_b_method.rb

module ModelBService
class ModelBMethod
 def initialize
 end
 def call
 .. logic goes here
 end
end
```

So, in your controller:

```
def method
   id = ModelBService::ModelBMethod.new.call
   .... some other stuff
end
```

If you want to pass arguments just `ModelBService::ModelBMethod.new(args).call` and fetch in initialize method